# Matching case sensitive unicode strings with regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, case-insensitive, character-properties

Suppose I want to match a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter, I could do something like

```
re.compile(r"[a-z][A-Z]")
```

Now I want to do the same thing for unicode strings, i.e. match something like 'aÅ' or 'yÜ'.

Tried

```
re.compile(r"[a-z][A-Z]", re.UNICODE)
```

but that does not work.

Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is hard to do with Python regex because the current implementation doesn't support Unicode property shortcuts like `\p{Lu}` and `\p{Ll}`.

`[A-Za-z]` will of course only match ASCII letters, regardless of whether the Unicode option is set or not.

So until the `re` module is updated (or you install the [`regex` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) currently in development), you either need to do it programmatically (iterate through the string and do `char.islower()`/`char.isupper()` on the characters), or specify all the unicode code points manually which probably isn't worth the effort...

Comment: This was useful. I only have to deal with Danish letters. So adding 'æøå' and 'ÆØÅ' is probably OK.